# Interactive matplotlib drawing not working in some environments

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, onclick

I have an interactive manual line/plot drawing solution using matplotlib and canvas.mpl_connect working on my Mac with PyCharm but it's completely non-interactive when the same script is run on my Linux box with either PyCharm or Sypder. The drawing canvas simply isn't waiting for the user to do any manual drawing whereas it does running the exact same script on my Mac. Is there something in my script that can be tweaked so that this solution is a bit more universal?

````
import pandas as pd
import os
from pathlib import Path
from matplotlib.widgets import TextBox
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.types import INTEGER, VARCHAR, DATETIME,TEXT
import mysql.connector

def onclick(event):
    xcoords.append(event.xdata)
    ycoords.append(event.ydata)

    # Update plotted coordinates
    graph_2.set_xdata(xcoords)
    graph_2.set_ydata(ycoords)

    # Refresh the plot
    fig.canvas.draw()
    if event.dblclick:
        row = [xcoords[0], ycoords[0]]
        list_of_rows.append(row)
        xcoords.clear()
        ycoords.clear()

    elif len(xcoords) == 2:
        row = [xcoords[0], ycoords[0], xcoords[1], ycoords[1]]
        list_of_rows.append(row)
        xcoords.clear()
        ycoords.clear()

# Get info up fron we we don't have to later
playerid = input('Enter player ID: ')
matchid= input('Please enter match ID: ')
event_type = input('Please enter event type: ')
teamid = input('Please enter team ID: ')
phase_type = input('Please enter phase type (return for OpenPlay: ')

if len(phase_type)<3:
    phase_type = 'OpenPlay'

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
plt.ylim(-3650, 3650)
plt.xlim(-5300, 5300)

data_folder = Path("")
filename = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), data_folder,'Pitch.png')
im = plt.imread(filename)
#implot = plt.imshow(im)

#fig = plt.figure()
#ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
# Plot some random data
#values = np.random.rand(4,1);
#graph_1, = ax.plot(values, label='original curve')
graph_2, = ax.plot([], marker='.')

# Keep track of x/y coordinates
xcoords = []
ycoords = []
list_of_rows = []

x0,x1 = ax.get_xlim()
y0,y1 = ax.get_ylim()
ax.imshow(im, extent=[x0, x1, y0, y1], aspect='auto', zorder=0)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
plt.show()

print(list_of_rows)

# Create empty dataframe to hold values once clicked on image
if event_type in ['Pass','Cross', 'SetPlay']:
    column_names = ['location_x', 'location_y', 'target_x', 'target_y']
elif event_type == 'Shot':
    column_names = ['location_x', 'location_y']```

Thanks in advance for any input/recommendations!
````

Answer (score 0):

plt.show(block=True) works like a charm. Waits for the window to be manually closed before proceeding. Not clear why this wasn't needed in my Mac environment.